# Converting a differential equation into a exact differential eqn

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

> Consider:
>   $$\cos x dy + y(y-\sin x) dx = 0 $$

How would I turn this into a perfect differential?

In my search for this I Found out I could use either integrating factor in terms of 'y' or integrating factor in terms of 'x', why is this?

Comment: What do you mean by perfect?

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Exact_differential

Comment: Since you know about "exact differential forms", you might edit the Question to use this more precise language.

Answer (score 0):

**hint**

If we put $$z=y\cos(x)$$ then 
$$dz=\frac{\partial z}{\partial x}dx+\frac{\partial z}{\partial y}dy$$
$$=-y\sin(x)dx+\cos(x)dy$$

your equation becomes

$$dz=-y^2dx$$
$$=-\frac{z^2}{\cos^2(x)}dx$$

Answer (score 0):

$$\cos x dy + y(y-\sin x) dx = 0$$
$$(\cos x dy -y \sin x dx ) + y^2 dx = 0$$
$$(\cos x dy +y d( \cos x) ) + y^2 dx = 0$$
$$d( {y\cos x}) + y^2 dx = 0$$
Divide by $y^2\cos ^2 x$:
$$\dfrac {dy\cos x}{y^2 \cos^2 x}  +  \dfrac {dx}{\cos ^2 x} = 0$$
It's exact you can integrate it.
$$-\dfrac {1}{y \cos x}  + {\tan  x} = K$$
$$y(x)=\dfrac {1}{\sin x - K\cos x } $$